# Manipulating the db with SQL Server 2005 - Django

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, django, pyodbc

I'm trying to accomplish the following:

- **Grab the db schema**
- **Grab any constraints***
- **Alter tables**
- **Add/Drop tables**

I'm currently using [pyodbc](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc) backend for Django.

I would like to perform all these tasks within a view file.

---

I'm using the following in order to grab fields of tables starting with 'core_':

```
SELECT  table_name,ordinal_position,column_name,data_type,
is_nullable,character_maximum_length FROM
information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE table_name LIKE 'core_%'
ORDER BY ordinal_position
```

***Fixed thanks to Madhivanan** [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149396/manipulating-the-db-with-sql-server-2005-django/3149421#3149421)

---

Any ideas to get started?

Answer (score 3):

Try this by using a wildcard %

```
SELECT  table_name,ordinal_position,column_name,data_type, 
is_nullable,character_maximum_length FROM 
information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE table_name LIKE 'core_%' 
ORDER BY ordinal_position
```